# InfluxQL query to Flux conversion

Tags: sql, database, influxdb, flux

I would like to switch from InfluxQL to flux, but now I want to convert the query:

```
SELECT sum("execution_duration") / sum("interval_duration) as "Availability" FROM "data-oee" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($time_interval)
```

To the flux language but can't quite get it done yet. What am I doing wrong here?

My Flux Query:

```
from(bucket: "Dashboard")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "oee-data")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["machine"] == "ilv")
  |> cumulativeSum(columns: ["duration"])
  |> cumulativeSum(columns: ["production_duration"])
  |> group(columns: ["_time"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

I've got the error:

```
 error @5:44-5:78: missing required argument tables
```

Comment: The table argument should come from the pipe (|>), and I can't seem to find a syntax error. What version of influx are you using ? Why are you grouping by the time column ?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT sum("execution_duration") / sum("interval_duration") as "Availability" FROM "data-oee" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($time_interval)

In this influx query I assume that you are only using data written in the query such as using the two column fields as "execution_duration" & "interval_duration" from the measurement named "data-oee" so, to divide the "_field" column based on different values stored in it, we have to use the pivot() function and then group the datails of both the query into one column using any computaion (like '+'/'-'/'*'/'/'), you need to use map() function. The query would go something like:

```
from(bucket: "Dashboard")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "oee-data")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["machine"] == "ilv")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "execution_duration" or r["_field"] == "interval_duration" )
  |> group(columns: ["_field"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _value: (r.execution_duration/r.interval_duration)}))  
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

the things that i'm not able to understand is why are you using the mean fumction in the aggregatewWindow when you have to caluculate the sum of the value in the column? may be this flux syntax will help someone.. I debugged it hard way.

thanks me later ;)